# Advice on backgrounding a task with variables?

Tags: python, process, background-process

I have a python webapp which accepts some data via POST. The method which is called can take a while to complete (30-60s), so I would like to "background" the method so I can respond to the user with a "processing" message.

The data is quite sensitive, so I'd prefer not to use any queue-based solutions. I also want to ensure that the backgrounded method doesn't get interrupted should the webapp fail in any way.

My first thought is to fork a process, however I'm unsure how I can pass variables to a process.

I've used [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) before, which has a handy method: `gevent.spawn(function, *args, **kwargs)`. Is there anything like this that I could use at the process-level?

Any other advice?

Comment: I don't understand the following: "The data is quite sensitive, so I'd prefer not to use any queue-based solutions." What's wrong with queues? If you're running on a malicious machine, queues are the least of your worries.

Comment: The way to do this is definitely to use a message queue (rabbitMQ and celary are two). You can run one of these on the same machine as your web application. As Katrielex says, there is no security benefit to doing this in a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use [a thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). Pass data to and from a thread with a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html).

Comment: I hope my sarcasm detector isn't broken -_-

Comment: I'm a people person! I am good a dealing with people!! WHAT THE HELL IS WRONG WITH YOU PEOPLE!!

Comment: @Aaron: this isn't the same queue. Read (& think) carefully